# How to preserve Markov Property in Deep Reinforcement Learning when using "mixup" or "mixreg"?

Tags: deep-rl, deep-neural-networks, data-augmentation

I've read through these two papers:

1. (original about "mixup") https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09412.pdf
2. (variant for RL, "mixreg") https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10814.pdf

They are about a rather interesting approach to improving model generalization. Here's the thing, though - I can easily see how to use this for supervised learning, as there is always a "reward"/prediction on each "observation"/row-of-data .

However, even though the second paper (mixreg) talks about applying this to RL specifically, I don't understand how you can manage this.

How would you preserve the Markov property if you're mixing observations/rewards that aren't necessarily in any way sequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each environment individually satisfies the Markov property, the distribution of the next state $s_{t+1}$ in any transition depends only on $s_t$, $a_t$, and the transition probabilities of the active environment $e_t$:

$$P(s_{t+1} | s_t, a_t) = P_{e_t}(s_t,a_t,s_{t+1})$$

Each environment is independent of the others, so when mixreg builds a combined state $(s_i, s_j, \lambda)$ and chooses an action $a$, the distribution of the next combined state $(s_{i+1}, s_{j+1}, \lambda)$ is simply the combined distribution:

$$P((s_{i+1}, s_{j+1}, \lambda) | (s_i, s_j, \lambda), a) = P_{e_i}(s_i,a,s_{i+1}) P_{e_j}(s_j,a,s_{j+1})$$

This remains conditionally independent of all other states and actions.

Comment: I see. So the Markov property is satisfied, even though that doesn't mean that there will be any signal to be found/remaining when mixing states. Is that correct? I might be destroying the signal, but Markov property is preserved?

Comment: Do you mean the rewards? Those are preserved, either using the reward from the environment with the bigger weight or a convex mixture of the two rewards

Comment: Got it, thank you for your answer! I have a related question here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/35941/how-to-deal-with-sparse-rewards-when-applying-mixup-or-mixreg-to-deep-reinfo  In case you are able and willing to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how mixreg changes things there, but in single environment RL, the agent learns in steps. First it learns that the state immediately before the reward is valuable, then the state immediately before that one, and so on.